# SwiftUI: how to make searchbar become first responder?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I would like to make the searchbar become first responder as soon as the view appears. Unfortunately there is no `@FocusState` support yet / other calls to achieve this out-of-the-box. Is there another way of achieving this?

```swift
struct SearchDemo: View {
    
    @State var searchString : String = ""
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List{
                Text("...")
            }
            .searchable(text: $searchString)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Having the same issue, I did find this article that proposes a view modifier to add the searchBar in a different way but still SwiftUI:
http://blog.eppz.eu/swiftui-search-bar-in-the-navigation-bar/

Answer (score 0):

A bit hacky, but you can get it working with [Introspect](https://github.com/siteline/SwiftUI-Introspect). It's not quite "soon as the view appears," but it's the best I've been able to figure out without rolling my own search controller.

```swift
struct SearchView: View {
     @State var searchText: String = ""

     var body: some View {
          NavigationStack {
               SomeList()
                    .searchable(text: $searchText)
          }
          .introspectSearchController(customize: { controller in
               DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.5) {
                    controller.searchBar.searchTextField.becomeFirstResponder()
               }
          })
     }
}
```